# Zend Framework : Incuding other controllers in index view

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-feed

I am new to Zend FW. I am looking to write a simple feedparser in a controller named Feedparsercontroller's indexAction. but i want to display the parsed feed output as a widget on my index page. how can i drive the output/ variable data to my indexview?

The below is my parser.

```
class FeedparserController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

public function init() {
    /* Initialize action controller here */
}

public function indexAction() {

    $feedUrl = 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/ZendScreencastsVideoTutorialsAboutTheZendPhpFrameworkForDesktop';
    $feed = Zend_Feed_Reader::import ( $feedUrl );

    $this->view->gettingStarted = array ();
    foreach ( $feed as $entry ) {
        if (array_search ( 'Getting Started', $entry->getCategories ()->getValues () )) {
            $this->view->gettingStarted [$entry->getLink ()] = $entry->getTitle ();
        }
    }
}

}
```

i want to implement the same with my login , register controllers as well.

Comment: If you don't want to call these controllers via url and only want them to be widgets, you don't need to put these stuff into a controller. Just write your own domain-object and include this in your view.

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for your reply, 
 i want to use it in a different controller coz i want to reuse the parser, say run as a cron job to fetch results from the feed, int he future. So i want to use it as a different controller and route the data to the Index View

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I'm not understanding your question fully.

But, it seems the best approach here would be to create a separate feed controller that is solely responsible for the business logic associated with feeds (retrieving, massaging, setting to view, etc).

Then, create a partial which contains javascript code to call the feed controller, which then outputs the widget you're desiring.  This does a few things very well.

1. It centralizes feed-related logic
2. It allows you to place the feed widget wherever you want
3. It is a SOA approach which is generally a good thing

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, 
I had the same idea, Using Ajax, But Is there any "mostly used" way to make it secure, i mean, i will be parsing the feed and applying my algorithm to get useful items from the feed, and out put it to a page say mysite.com/feedparser/jsonview, how can i secure it from remote calls using Zend.

Comment: Hi Eswar,

Generally speaking, this protection is the job of the system firewall, not the application itself.  If you are making AJAX calls, then all of the calls to the controller will be from outside sources, unless of course this is an internal application.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best logic with widgets is **ajax**.

Use some js **widgets** libraries (maybe jQuery ui for example), then make these widgets be loaded by some ajax queries, returning HTML, this allow you as well simple widgets reloading behviours (without relaoding the whole page).

In the server Side you'll need to allow your controller/Action to be called via ajax requests and to send only html snippets (not a whole page with all the layout).

To do that check [ContextSwitch and AjaxContext](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html) Action Helpers. You will tell your FeedparserController that the index action can be called with /format/html in an XMLHHTTPRequest, and that in this case the view helper will be index.

In the init part you will say the indexAction can be called in ajax mode, rendering html snippets ('html'):

```
$Ajaxcontext = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
$Ajaxcontext->addActionContext('index', 'html')
            ->initContext();
```

Now simply rename your view script `feedparser/index.phtml` to `feedparser/index.ajax.phtml`

In the indexAction, do your stuff and output what you want on your view script, do not think about layout composition problems, you're working alone with your own layout part and the composition is done on the js side.

In the javascript part, ensure you're calling via ajax ($.load or $.ajax with jQuery maybe) the url with format/html added as parameters (so http://example.com/feedparser/index/format/html)

Note that in my opinion you should use json responses and not html, maybe json with some html inside. But that's a matter on how you want to control your ajax communication (and handle errors, redirection and such, and it's another subject).

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply, 
I had the same idea, Using Ajax, But Is there any "mostly used" way to make it secure, i mean, i will be parsing the feed and applying my algorithm to get useful items from the feed, and out put it to a page say mysite.com/feedparser/jsonview, how can i secure it from remote calls using Zend.

Comment: @Eswar Rajesh Pinapala : this is another question :-) check for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982284/securing-an-ajax-api-to-prevent-other-sites-from-taking-advantage-of-it

Answer (score 0):

What about a view helper ?

You can read about it [View Helpers in Zend Framework](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3412)

Comment: Thanks , i am new to Zend Framework, and i will read in detail about Helpers and see if it can help.